# How to access the file generated inside docker container by defining the volume in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-volume, docker-container

I am rookie when it comes to docker container , can somebody help me here.

There is a project which generates a output files when running inside docker container , I need to add **Volume** inside docker-compose.yml file, So that the output files are accessible **outside the container**.

Please do provide me indetail knowledge of how can I do this?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Hi @DanielW, I read it earlier I didn't get it how to use in my case, can you please me here, It would be great , Thanks!

Comment: What didn't you get? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Daly, I have never worked on Docker container before, So I did trail n error thing, it was not working, hence I have asked here, please do let me your thoughts I would appreciate that, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Define volumes in the `docker-compose.yml` file, mapping source on the server to target in the container:

```
volumes:
  - "./relative/path/on/host:/absolute/path/in/container:rw"
```

Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose

There hopefully should be a `readme.md` file in the project which lists the options on how to get the output (files).